# No space left on device, space and inodes available on NTFS drive

Tags: disk-usage, storage, ntfs

When I try to make new directories (with `mkdir`) or files (even empty ones with `touch`) on an external NTFS hard drive that I use for personal backups, filesystem operations fail with `No space left on device`.

Here is what `df` has to say about space and inode usage of the drive:

```
$ df -it fuseblk
Filesystem        Inodes   IUsed     IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      156579976 3240128 153339848    3% /mnt/hd
$ df -ht fuseblk
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       932G  786G  147G  85% /mnt/hd
```

There appears to be still lots of space left. Since even making directories was a problem, at first I thought this was an inodes issue, but only 3% of the quota has been filled.

What else could be causing this problem?

Comment: As it is NTFS, have you tried `chkdsk` on Windows? (Make sure not to use the *fix* option without backup - but running it without options should report any issues). Also check `dmesg`, perhaps it has some relevant data. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chkdsk - One can also mount it with debug option. I.e. `mount -o debug ...` (run that in a terminal you keep open).

Comment: There is also `sudo ntfsfix -n /dev/sda1` (See `man ntfsfix` , from `ntfsprogs`). The `-n` option makes sure nothing is written. (Only show what would potentially be done.) Disk need to be unmounted before check.